# .htaccess http to https redirect all pages to homepage

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-redirect

I just purchase my site SSL license, I googled and try a few different codes to be added to htaccess.

1st set of code I used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

2nd set of code I used

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

ref:https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

However, the site keep redirects all inner pages without https to https homepage.

Eg. http://example.com/tag1/tag2 to https://example.com

But I need it to redirect from http://example.com/tag1/tag2 to https://example.com/tag1/tag2

Is there something wrong with my code? or it server configuration related?

Comment: Your #1 rule looks like it should work. How exactly did it fail?

Comment: Is htaccess located inside /subfolder?

Comment: the redirect didn't failed, but all my inner pages is going to homepage instead of the page itself with https